# Why tortoise hangs during pull?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I do not know why but my project tortoise often hangs when I try to do a pull?

In tortoise, it is written:
pulling from http://home.com:8000
searching for changes

searching 2

And it hangs so long. Does anyone have an idea? A solution to offer, I'm looking on the web but nothing. I completely blocked because of this problem.

Thxs

Answer (score 0):

Probably has nothing to do with Tortoise, but the network connection or the server you're updating from.

You could run wireshark on your network connection to see any data its retrieving (or not, if its not receiving any..)